# Trying to figure out how can I make a program to identify equal numbers

Tags: java

so my real question is, how can i make this code identify all the "look alike" numbers while theire running from 1 to 99, for example :11,22,33,44,...
and while the program identify them it sends a message.

```
package doodle;

int num2=11;
for (int i=1; i<100; i++) {
    System.out.println(i);
    int num1=i;
    if(num1==num2) {
        System.out.println("WOW"); 
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do, and what exactly is(n't) working? why do you need this num1 variable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if integer has repeating digits. No string methods or arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26748026/check-if-integer-has-repeating-digits-no-string-methods-or-arrays)

Comment: If you mean numbers with repeating digits between 1 and 99, then that are only the numbers that are divisible by 11.

Comment: What do you mean by "look alike"? numbers composed of twice the same digit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do using a String

```
for (int i = 11; i < 100; i++) {
    StringBuffer orig = new StringBuffer();
    String left = orig.append(i).toString();
    if (orig.reverse().toString().equals(left)) {
        System.out.println(left);
    }
}
```

or if you really wanted to use an `int` with flaky logic

```
int start = 11;
for (int i = 11; i < 100; i++) {
    if (i == start) {
        System.out.println(start);
        start += 11;
    }
}
```

**Edit**

As @mark has rightly pointed out, these solution only work whilst the range is up to 100

Comment: Note that the first method only works for `i < 100`, after `100` it will match with palindromes of numbers aswell like `121`, `131` etc.. Which is also what the question specified but it's good to know either way.

Comment: @Mark Yep, the requirements are not clear at all, but there maybe be a limit of 100

Comment: @Mark While true, the domain here is  `11 <= i < 100` (as the for loop states), so the problem doesn't exist

Comment: @BackSlash Just pointing it out if someone in the future comes across this answer and decides they want to use it for `i < 1000` or something

Comment: @Mark I have updated my answer with the disclaimer.

Answer (score 1):

```
int num2=11;
for (int i=1; i<100; i++) {
    if(i%num2==0) {  //<---- look alike
        System.out.println("WOW");
         }
```

Comment: `121%11` would pass aswell.

Comment: check the range of i. i ranges from 1 to 99

Comment: `if(i%num2==0)`

Comment: @ScaryWombat they are same

Comment: Yes, so why use a magic number in the code?  BTW I did not downvote you.

Comment: @ScaryWombat thanks for pointing that out. I have fixed it.

Comment: Please also do not answer questions with code only answers.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it using String conversion and codePoint comparison

```
for (Integer number = 0; number < 1000; number++) {
    System.out.println(number);

    String stringnumber = String.valueOf(number);

    if (stringnumber.length() > 1 && stringnumber.codePoints().allMatch((digit) -> digit == stringnumber.codePointAt(0))) {
            System.out.println("WOW");
    }
}
```

length check (length() > 0) is needed to exclude all numbers with only one digit, otherwise, the program would print `"WOW"` for all numbers from `0 - 9` too.

All numbers from `0` to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` can be handled.